# Using Intents to switch between classes

Tags: android

I have a 'home page' on my app with a button in.  I have implemented an onClickListener. I want to change to a different class when clicking the button. (Navigating to another page within the app with a different XML file)  What am I doing wrong??

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, menu_two.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);
```

That is in the code which goes in a switch statement which identifies which button has been pressed. I am not using an XML file, layout hard coded straight from java.

Home I have given you enough information to help

thanks

Comment: What are the negative effects that you are seeing?  Does it throw an exception (force close)?  Not compile? If it throws an exception, what does logcat say?  Open the DDMS perspective in eclipse, or run `adb logcat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that `menu_two` is an activity. If you are not using an XML, that shouldn't be a problem. Also, verify that you added menu_two to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, where you must register all activities that your app uses.

Comment: I managed to get it working thanks. The current class I am on called menuActivity. This is one of the tabs of a TabHost. How do I add the Tabs onto the menu_two class? Ive tried copying the code that generates the tabs but it is not working. This is because to change page using the intent statement 'extends Activity' is needed at the top on the line starting with public class. To implement the Tabs 'extends TabActivity' is needed instead, and i cant have both. Think of any way around this?

Comment: I think you must create a different question for that. Don't forget to include relevant snippets of your code and explain your problems.